# Notification theme broken

Tags: 13.04, themes, notification

I have an almost fresh Ubuntu 13.04 installation. The only thing I did was adding a PPA for the [i3 window manager](http://i3wm.org/docs/repositories.html), and of course installed i3. However, I don't know if the problem I have relates to that.

My notifications look very strange. Removing the stuff I installed from the aforementioned PPA did not help. Ideas, anyone?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had this problem and finally figured it out. You need to remove dunst. It's a notification daemon that is installed with i3. Simply removing i3 will not fix your problem. If you want to run both Unity and i3 on the same machine you'll have to kill the dunst daemon at Unity startup.